# How to start a Service even if we force the application in Android.?

Tags: android

I created an Activity and started a service in that activity.The service should run in the background even if we make the application to force close.Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: services are made to run in background.its services behaviour.can you tell me what exactly want to do?

Comment: In my application I have entered some date and saved in database,repeatedly the service should be called so that i want to check the dates in the database with the present date and so some action if they are equal.

Comment: i think you need to check all date with current data in loop and keep that process in asynctask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Services run on the same proccess of its application. For this, they should die if its application is force closed.

Maybe you should think about using different threads:
[Processes and Threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html)

Answer (score 0):

When app gets force close then service gets destroyed.
Check out below link, which shows a Return value from onstartCommand func.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY
By this system restarts service.
Check this also.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_CONTINUATION_MASK
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_REDELIVER_INTENT